# get date from number of excel cell

Tags: java, excel

I'm using org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory to read excel files. Unfortunately, for date cells it gives only a number. How do I convert that back into a date?

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
int value = (int)cell.getNumericCellValue();
```

Comment: Have you tried getDateCellValue()?